# how to fix the problem to complete the build?

Tags: bitbake

I am struggling with build error which show "oe_runmake failed."
Does anyone have an idea to solve this error ??

I am using Ubuntu20.04 on VMware.
To conduct build, right now use "bitbake imx-image-core" command.

here, I wrote down terminal log below...
Excerpt error part from the whole log

==========

```
| {standard input}: Assembler messages:
| {standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
| g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
| compilation terminated.
| make[1]: *** [Makefile:1143: gimple-match.o] Error 1
| make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| rm gcc.pod
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/test/imx-yocto-bsp/L5.15.32-2.0.0/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-aarch64/11.2.0-r0/gcc-11.2.0/build.x86_64-linux.aarch64-poky-linux/gcc'
| make: *** [Makefile:4443: all-gcc] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/test/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_11.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 276 tasks of which 0 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/test/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_11.2.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried editting a file, "conf/local.conf", by adding some sentences, but I am not sure wether what types of sentence is appropriate to fix my problem...

if more info needed, I can add them.

Comment: The "open CFI..." error usually it's an out of memory one, so I would check the amount of memory that you have available. have a look with `htop` for example

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can I ask you something? What does "htop" mean , like you said... I have recently started learning this area... and sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: `htop` is a command line program, the evolution of `top`. It's a process viewer, gives you information on the processes running on your computer. More info here: https://htop.dev/
PS: I don't want to be rude, but as a suggestion, Yocto is a quite advanced topic of embedded Linux programming. Commands like top/htop are the very first principles to learn, so maybe you should take your time before getting lost in Yocto. What device are you working on? Modern embedded devices often offers more simple distributions, like Ubuntu, you could start with that maybe.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Like you said, I may have to try top/htop Command.
I am now running on ubuntu 20.04.